# ChartJS not working in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am making a little productivity app/game to make my self feel better about all the time I waste. I am using vue and chartjs and the don't seem to play nice with each other.

When I include my `<canvas>` element in `<div id="app">`, the one vue is initiated on chartjs fails to render anything. There are no errors or anything. However, when I move `<canvas>` outside of `<div id="app">` it works perfectly. Doesn't anyone have any insight in this?

HTML

```
<body>

  <div id="app">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>GAME OF LIFE!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="character_container">
      <div class="health_bar">
        <div class="life"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="character">
        <img id="sprite" src="imgs/melee/1.png" width="100" height="100px">
        <div class="stats">
          <p>ed</p>
          <p>3</p>
          <p>3</p>
          <p>da</p>
          <p>adf</p>
          <p>adf</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard">
      <h2>GAME DATA</h2>
      <input type="date" name="viewDate" v-model="viewDate">
    </div>
    <!-- Doesn't work when canvas inside #app -->
    <div class="canvas">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Works when the canvas is outside #app -->
  <!-- <div class="canvas">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div> -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vue.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
    const day = ( x => {
      let date = (t => new Date(t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth(), t.getDate(), 0, 0, 0))(new Date());
      return new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + x));
    });
    const padDate = (x => (x.toString().length <= 1? '0'+ x : x));
    const format = (x => formatDate(new Date(x)));
    const formatDate =  (fd => padDate(fd.getUTCMonth() + 1)+'/'+padDate(fd.getUTCDate())+'/'+fd.getUTCFullYear()+' 00:00');

    const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/logs';
    const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

    const chartConfig = {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
          type: 'bar',
          label: 'Productivity',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .5)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, .5)',
          data: [],
        }, {
          type: 'line',
          label: 'Code Written',
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)',
          fill: false,
          data: [],
        }, ]
      },
      options: {
                title: {
                    text:"Productivity Graph"
                },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            type: "time",
            display: true,
            time: {
              format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
              round: 'day',
              unit: 'day'
            }
          }],
        },
      }
    };

    function fetchData() {
      return fetch(serverUrl).then(function (res){
        return res.json();
      })
    }

    function dateToISO(date) {
      var msec = Date.parse(date);
      return new Date(msec).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    }



    function updateLog(logData){
      const headers = {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "PUT",
        body:  JSON.stringify(logData)
      };
      return fetch('http://localhost:3000/logs',headers).then(function(res){
        return res.json();
      });
    }

    function runSprite(){
      // NOTE https://www.gameart2d.com/the-robot---free-sprites.html
      // NOTE Melee(Good) 8, Run(Normal) 8, DEAD(Bad) 10
      let path = 'imgs/';
      let i = app.sprite.index;
      switch (app.sprite.status) {
        case 'good':
          path += 'melee/';
          i = (i >= 26 ? 1 : ++i);
          break;
        case 'avg':
          path += 'run/';
          i = (i >= 8 ? 1 : ++i);
          break;
        case 'bad':
          path += 'dead/';
          i = (i >= 10 ? 1 : ++i);
          break;  
      }
      path += i;
      app.sprite.index = i;
      document.querySelector('#sprite').src = path + ".png";
    }

    setInterval(runSprite, 100);

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        viewDate:  new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10),
        sprite: {
          status: 'good',
          index: 1
        },
        logs: [],
        log:{},
        chart: chartConfig,
        line: '',
        productivityMinutesGoal: 560,
        projectsMinutesGoal: 300,
        health_bar: 100,
        visible: true
      },
      methods : {
        updateChart: function(data, build = false){
          this.logs = data;
          const productivityAverages = this.logs
                                      .map(x => x.productivity)
                                      .reduce((a, b, index, self) => {
                                         const keys = Object.keys(a)
                                         let c = {} 
                                         keys.map((key) => {
                                          c[key] = a[key] + b[key]
                                          if (index + 1 === self.length) {
                                            c[key] = c[key] / self.length
                                          }
                                         })
                                         return c
                                      });

          const projectsAverages = this.logs
                                      .map(x => x.projects.data[0].grand_total)
                                      .reduce((a, b, index, self) => {
                                         const keys = Object.keys(a)
                                         let c = {} 
                                         keys.map((key) => {
                                          c[key] = a[key] + b[key]
                                          if (index + 1 === self.length) {
                                            c[key] = c[key] / self.length
                                          }
                                         })
                                         return c
                                      });

          // above 90% equals + to health_bar;
          // below 90% equals - to health_bar; 
          // below 50% should equal death;
          this.health_bar += ((projectsAverages.hours * 60 + projectsAverages.minutes) / this.projectsMinutesGoal ) - 90;
          this.health_bar += ((productivityAverages.software_development_hours * 60) / this.productivityMinutesGoal ) - 90;
          this.health_bar = Math.round(this.health_bar);
          document.querySelector('.health_bar .life').setAttribute('style','width:'+ (100 + this.health_bar)+'%;');
          const loggedData = this.logs
                            .map(x => {return {
                              date:x.date, 
                              projectTimeMinutes:((x.projects.data[0].grand_total.hours * 60) + x.projects.data[0].grand_total.minutes - (projectsAverages.hours * 60 + projectsAverages.minutes)), 
                              productivitySoftwareMinutes: (x.productivity.software_development_hours * 60 - (productivityAverages.software_development_hours * 60))}
                            })
                            .sort((a,b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));

          loggedData.forEach(x => {
            this.chart.data.labels.push(format(x.date));
            this.chart.data.datasets[0].data.push(x.productivitySoftwareMinutes);
            this.chart.data.datasets[1].data.push(x.projectTimeMinutes);

          });
          // Handle Build default update
          if(build){
            this.line = new Chart(ctx, this.chart);
          }else{
            this.line.update();
          }
        }  

      },
      computed: {
        dateIsValid: function (){
          return this.friend.name.length == 0 || this.friend.feature.length == 0;
        }
      },
      created: function (){
        fetchData().then(function (data){
          app.updateChart(data, true);
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: You should use https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs, it was made exactly for that.

Comment: Vue **_owns_** that `canvas` element - and you haven't asked it for permission to mess with it. If you place the canvas into a component (it can be simple) it will work like a charm - because you asked nicely :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn that sounds great and all but how do I ask it nicely?

Comment: Don't say I never gave you anything :-). Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a StackBlitz for your reference. All this does is allow Vue to have some awareness of what you are doing. Please let me know you have any other questions.

https://vue-wpbxue.stackblitz.io

```js
<template>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px"></canvas>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    draw: function(ctx) {
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "# of Votes",
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
                "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
              ],
              borderColor: [
                "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
                "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
                "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    this.draw(ctx);
  }
}
  
</script>

<style>
canvas {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
</style>
```

Comment: I copied the code verbatim from the codepen. The html from the component is rendering, but nothing from chartjs.

Comment: You are using chartjs for you codepen right?  I am justing using `  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>` is that the wrong cdn to use?

Comment: _Wrong cdn_ - I just used the one from ChartJS website.

Comment: that cdn looks like it is for momentjs rather than ChartJS?

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script> ` sorry this is the one I meant to copy over, but it all seems good now.

Comment: Awesome - glad to help.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, you mad my day. Thanks

Comment: sorry, im having a hard time following this. if i wanted to add this to my chart how would i go about doing so? im new to both vue.js and chart.js so its hard for me to see where one begins and the other ends. and i notice that it specifies `<canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="800px"></canvas>` up the top. does this mean that it will only work on 800 by 800 canvases?

Comment: @sorry.vol - the Vue thing is a component. It offers a `draw` method. Within that method the chart is created and displayed. The canvas is not restricted to 800x800, that was arbitrary, but necessary for canvas to size properly.

Comment: @RandyCasburn is this example for vue 2? im not sure of the differences but ive tried to sample it in my code and it doesnt seem to be working, if so what do i have to change to get it working in vue 3?

Comment: @sorry.vol - I updated the code in the answer and changed the link to a StackBlitz that  is using Vue 3. Works like a charm. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @RandyCasburn im sure it's obvious but im new to Vue and Javascript as a whole and i don't quite understand why im getting an error from the `export` part of the code. i think its something to do with es6 or node.js maybe? but im not using node.js, if i should be how would i go about getting that up and running? also i cant seem to access the stackblitz that you linked.

Comment: @sorry.vol - it sounds as if you need to ask a new question to address "_i don't quite understand why im getting an error from the export part of the code_" and "_how would i go about getting that up and running_" - StackOverflow frowns upon extending one question/answer with an ongoing conversation that is not directly related to the OP's question. Thanks and good luck.